# Android error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [generic]

Tags: android, eclipse

I have got this error report from one user of my Android app:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [generic]
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That's the whole stack trace. O_o

Not very informative...

The only external jar I use is GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar for AdMob, and it is on the libs directory and added to the project through Eclipse's Android Interface (you know: Properties / Java Build Path / Libraries / Add External JARs)

So I have not a clue about what's wrong.

Any hints?

I compile using Eclipse v3.7.0 Build id I20110613-1736 on Ubuntu 11.04 with ADT 18.0.0.v20120330

I forgot to mention that my app has been installed by thousands of users and I only get one report on this issue til today.

Comment: what version of android sdk are you using?  I think I had the same issue, but I could only get my app working with version 4 of the admob sdk.

Comment: Are you pointing to the right class/activity to start in your manifest?

Comment: John: I am using Android 3.2 as target SDK and 2.1 and Android 2.1 as minimum (android.targetSdkVersion="13" and android.minSdkVersion="5" on manifest).

Now I see that minSdkVersion seems to be 7, but I think that does not make difference because: a) there is no SDK version between 4 and 7, so I think 5 will have the same effect as 7 and b) I have used the same values for min and target sdk versions on other app manifest and never get that error report after 15000+ active installs.

Comment: Cruceo: The activity is right there. If it weren't, it should fail at every run, and it does not by far.

Comment: you've tried running a `clean` on your project, right?

Comment: @John You mean Source/Clean up, isn't it?

Comment: @Fran, yes that's what I meant.

Comment: same stack trace got reported for me, device is **Xperia U (ST25i)**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that they are launching with the same `CLASSPATH` as everyone else.  (This could be due to a truncated command line.)

This should appear in your `javac` command line: `-classpath=libs/*.jar`

This should appear in your `apkbuilder` command line: `-rj libs`

Comment: Eclipse should take care of all those things, and just in case it didn't, the error should be easily reproducible and fail in every app install, even for me in my device and emulator. 

But that's not the case. I have never experiment such error by myself and so many users, since nobody has complained about after 2500+ active installs and I have received just one error report.

It should be something specific to a device or Android OS version. Unfortunatly the only information that I have is that brief stack trace.

Comment: @Fran - Did that user deploy directly from Eclipse?  I thought it was an end user.

Comment: @Fran - anyway, the error message simply says that `libs` is not on your `CLASSPATH`, or that one of your external jars is missing from `libs`, so that is what you should check and fix.

Comment: Of course it is a end user, but the package is generated from eclipse anyway. It has downloaded and install the same package that I export signed with Eclipse Android Tools, move into my SD card using DDMS, and installed from there. And so the rest of 2500+ users that has not got into that trouble. I even install my app sometimes from Google Play to check that everything goes ok.

The error message does not say a word on libs, although it may be implicit, isn't it? it says "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [generic]". If at least "generic" where some class name that I were using... O_o